# I made a model too tall, how do I chop the bottom part off?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I made a ship model and mid-way into the making I said "Hey, that looks a lot like a rowboat". But I'm not sure how to delete the other half of the model that is too big.

Here's an image of the boat: (should be fairly obvious where I want to cut)
[image: The boat]

EDIT: I tried deleting all the vertices at the bottom, but that just created a large hole in the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way, but it's simple and clean.

1. I hit **z** to enter wireframe mode.
2. Then **NumPad_1** to enter front view mode (depending on how your
   boat is orientated, it could be **NumPad 3**, side view)
3. Then **b** to box select the bottom faces (one row before the
   vertices you want to keeP)
4. Then **x** and *Delete Vertices*
5. Making sure I had the [vertex select mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html) on, I clicked one
   vertex away from the corner, held **CTRL** and right clicked the
   point opposite it which was one vertex away from the opposite
   corner. (Holding control while right-clicking selects the shortest
   path between selections). I do the same for the other side of the
   boat.
6. Then **Space** and type in *Bridge Edge Loops*
7. I hit **CTRL + r** to enter loop cut mode and hover my cursor over the newly made row of planks and type in the number of loop cuts I want to be made. I made it 2 because I had 2 middle vertices I needed to be joined with something. Then once the pink lines are where you want, hit **Enter** twice.
8. Finally, use **b** to box select, **c** to circle select, or simply
   right-click the vertices left and hit **f** to join them into faces.
   Do this by sets of 4, not all at once.

[image]

Or, try selecting the hole's perimeter with **Alt + Right Click** then hitting **Space** and typing in **[Grid Fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html)**. Sometimes that works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting the bottom faces, then select the edges and press F, that'll create a Ngon, if you want only quads you can [bridge edge loop between each edge in the bottom](https://youtu.be/i_XEwueSUz4)